# Is it possible to open or use a functor without an intermediate module in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Is it possible to open or use a functor without an intermediate module?  For example, say we have the following set of modules and functors:

```
module type FOO = sig
    val foo : int -> int
end
module Foo1 : FOO = struct
    let foo x = x+1
end
module Foo2 : FOO = struct
    let foo x = x+2
end

module Bar(Foo : FOO) = struct
    open Foo
    let apply x = foo x
end
```

If we try

```
let _ = Bar(Foo1).apply 1
```

we get the error

```
Error: Parse error: currified constructor
```

Certainly, we can accomplish this with

```
let _ =
    let module Bar' = Bar(Foo1) in
    Bar'.apply 1
```

but it's a little verbose.  Alternatively, if we define a module that uses a functor

```
module Buz(Foo : FOO) = struct
    open Bar(Foo) 
    let buz x = apply x
end
```

we get the error

```
Error: This module is not a structure; it has type
       functor (Foo : FOO) -> sig val apply : int -> int end
```

Again, we can fix this with

```
module Buz(Foo : FOO) = struct
    module M = Bar(Foo)
    open M
    let buz x = apply x
end
```

but it's more verbose.  In addition, we have a new module `M` defined in `Buz`, which sort of pollutes the namespace

```
module Buz :
  functor (Foo : FOO) ->
    sig module M : sig val apply : int -> int end val buz : int -> int end
```

Really, I just want `Buz` to include `buz`.

Basically, I'm asking if there's some sort of syntax or trick that I'm missing that let's us write things like `Bar(Foo1).apply` or `open Bar(Foo1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip instantiation of a functor if you're accessing a type, module type, or class type. In other words it is possible only inside type expressions. Example:

```
module type T = sig type t end
module Pair (T : T) = struct type t = T.t * T.t end
module Int = struct type t = int end
type int_pair = Pair(Int).t
```

What concerning the second part of your question, then if you really want "want Buz to include buz.", then you should use `include`:

```
 module Buz(Foo : FOO) = struct
    include Bar(Foo) 
    let buz x = apply x
 end
```

There is difference between `open` and `include` statement. `open X` will not add any definitions from `X`, but just add it into a search path. `include X` will merely copy paste all definitions from `X` into the point where it is included.

If you want only `buz` in your module and nothing more, then you can hide it using module signatures:

```
module type Buz = sig val buz : int -> int end

module Buz(Foo : FOO) : Buz = struct
  include Bar(Foo)
  let buz = apply
end
```

Comment: In the second case, if possible, I don't want the additional definitions at all.  Really, I just want `buz` to be in the signature and it would be nice to do so without having to define a new signature by hand.

Comment: you cannot do this in OCaml. There are reasons for this. The main reason, is that modules can have arbitrary side effects and nontrivial representation. And they need a place to live.